# Intellij Idea does not show JUnit and Hamcrest import options

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, hamcrest

As already mentioned in the title I'm having troubles to get the autoimport/-completion working for Hamcrest and JUnit (Maven project).

[image: Problem]

What I already tried:

- invalidated the caches
- checked the exclude options in the auto import settings
- added the packages to Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports Tab --> Packages to Use Import with "*"

Additional Info:

- When adding the import manually in the class and deleting it again, it will be shown in the autocompletion/-import

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project for investigation?

Comment: thats not possible, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a maven project, you can try to refresh it using maven command interface.

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion, but this didn't solve it :)